# XAMPP php file upload to folder failed

Tags: php

I am using xampp on my local desktop and created an folder named image.

Path:   `C:/xampp/htdocs/mycreation/ch-5/images/`.

In **ch-5** folder i have my php file and also images folder.

now how can i define a `$target_dir`  to that images folder.

Comment: use `move_uploaded_file` function to move the uploaded file to the desired location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define target dir something like:

```
$target_dir = "images/";
```

Answer (score 0):

$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mycreation/ch-5/images/";

Answer (score 0):

create one folder(uploads) inside htdocs/ch-5 and try this code,,..

```
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
    $image_path="uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

for uploading files you can use `move_uploaded_file` function, which takes the current file and the location you want to save that file.

```
$file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$target_dir = "images/"; //images directory

if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $target_dir . $file_name)) {
     echo "Uploaded file";
else
    echo "Failed to upload image";
```